# Android : Writing part of text file to another file

Tags: android

I have a multipart format text file. i am going threw the file looking for start of content and from then on writing the content to another file until i hit end of content.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(getContentPath());

InputStreamReader sr = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");

BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(sr);

String lineStr;

while ((lineStr = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {

    if (lineStr == "") {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("", true);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");

    BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
    fbw.write(lineStr);
    fbw.newLine();
    fbw.flush();
    fbw.close();
    }
}
```

The problem i am getting is the resulting files encoding is all messed up. The input is utf8.

[Original in multipart format](http://www.2shared.com/file/w04lFJT3/request_-1311485219e5071873-c2.html)

[Just image file extracted(funny-pictures-bomb-squad-cat-chooses-the-blue-wire.jpg)](http://www.2shared.com/file/w04lFJT3/request_-1311485219e5071873-c2.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem the input charset was not utf8 it is iso-8859-1 http default.

Used CharsetDecoder to make sure i read/saved string as iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(highscoresFile, true);

The boolean at the end tells you whether or not to append to the end of the file.